# point as array index

Tags: c, pointers

My background is C#, I have the following code(in C) that I need to tell what would be the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10
int main()
{
    int a[N] = { 3,4 };       //<-- [3][4][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
    int *q = a;              //<-- some address
    char s[N] = "abcdefg"; 
    int k = s[*a] - s[a[*q]]; //<-- what is that mean ?
    char *p = s;
    a[k] = k;
    printf("%d %s\n",k,p+a[k]);
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d",q[0],q[1],q[2],q[3],q[4]);
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain about line number 4?

I can't understand `s[*a]` is that mean `s` at index of `*a`? but `*a` is address not an integer. same question about `s[a[*q]]`

Comment: `*a` is the same as `a[0]`.

Comment: Also `*a` is not ad address; it's an `int`. Please consider changing the title of your question into something useful describing your problem.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Hi, can you please explain about `s[a[*q]]` also?

Comment: You need to read the chapter dealing with pointers in your C text book. You should know the array part already from c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering

```
int k = s[*a] - s[a[*q]];
```

First `*a` gets the value at `a[0]` which is `3`.

We know that `q == a` so `*q` is the same as `*a` which again is the value `3`. The value at `a[3]` is `0`.

So now we have `s[3] - s[0]` which is `'d' - 'a'` which is `3` (assuming ASCII encoding), the value printed out for `k`.

Answer (score 0):

Without the rest of the code, it is unclear if it will work at all. What is N, for example?

Specifically, `s[*a]`: `a` is the name of an array. `*a` is the same as `a[0]`, because `a` is a pointer to the first element. So `*a` is `3`, and `s[*a]` is `s[3]`, which is the character `'d'`

Comment: Technically wrong (`a` is an array, not a pointer), but morally right: It gets converted to a pointer automatically.

Comment: Isn't `s[3]` the value `'d'`?

Comment: Hi, can you please explain about `s[a[*q]]` also?